# Regular Expression conditional lookahead with next capture group match PCRE

Tags: php, regex, conditional-statements, pcre, capture-group

I searched for answer and I did not found anything about that.
hopefully that you can help me with my question.

So I try to search after string with lookahead conditional based on capture group at the end of a string.
It means if the capture group at the end is a match, make the conditional group be with something and if capture group at the end is not a match so with something else.

[See my regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/u1JJOg/2)

```
(?:((?(?=ls)yes|no))\${(?:(?P<type>VAR)\s+)([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\s*\=\s*(\$\{CALL\s+[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*\s*\}|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[0-9]*|(?:[fF]alse|[tT]rue))\s*\}(?<ls>[^\s]{1}))
```

Input:

```
    ${VAR foo="What"}x

    ${VAR foo="What"} 

    yes${VAR foo="What"}

    no${VAR foo="What"}x
```

As you see, it captures the word 'no' if there is something at the end as long it is not \s, but it did not capture the word 'yes' if it is nothing.

Comment: `(?(?=ls)yes|no)` never matches 'yes'. The conditional says if next two immediate characters are `ls` then match `yes`. No way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern contains `(?(?=ls)yes|no)` which is literally looking ahead for the characters `ls`. I've changed your pattern to utilize the `DEFINE` construct for subpattern reusability. As far as I'm aware, PCRE does not have a method to check whether or not a group was defined *after* the conditional. This can be accomplished in [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) with the use of balancing groups, but PCRE doesn't employ those methods. PCRE does have the `(?(name)yes|no)` or `(?(1)yes|no)` conditional, but it doesn't work for forward references (comparative to testing whether or not a variable exists before it's even declared).

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/u1JJOg/5)

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?# var )
  (?<var>[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][\w\x7f-\xff]*)
  (?# val )
  (?<val>(?&call)|(?&str)|(?&num)|(?&bool))
  (?<call>\$\{CALL\s+[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][\w\x7f-\xff]*\s*\})
  (?<str>"[^"]*"|'[^']*')
  (?<num>\d+)
  (?<bool>(?i)(?:false|true)(?-i))
)
((?(?=yes\${VAR\s+(?&var)\s*\=\s*(?&val)\s*\}\s)yes|no))
\${(?P<type>VAR)\s+((?&var))\s*\=\s*((?&val))\s*\}(\S)?
```

Without duplicating the subpattern in the positive lookahead, you can use the following ([as seen in use here](https://regex101.com/r/u1JJOg/7)). The token `(?8)` recurses the 8th capture group:

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?# var )
  (?<var>[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][\w\x7f-\xff]*)
  (?# val )
  (?<val>(?&call)|(?&str)|(?&num)|(?&bool))
  (?<call>\$\{CALL\s+[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][\w\x7f-\xff]*\s*\})
  (?<str>"[^"]*"|'[^']*')
  (?<num>\d+)
  (?<bool>(?i)(?:false|true)(?-i))
)
((?(?=no(?8)\S)no|yes))
(\${(?P<type>VAR)\s+((?&var))\s*\=\s*((?&val))\s*\})(\S)?
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the answer, i learned a lot from that (you show me some new things and ways to do somethings). just another question for me, making new line in pattern like you doing is possible in PHP pattern (what i means it is not should be in one line without any breakline)?

Comment: *As far as I'm aware, PCRE does not have a method to check whether or not a group was defined* would you explain it please?

Comment: @Almog you mean the white space in the pattern? It’s because I added the `x` modifier which makes the regex engine ignore white space in the pattern. It’s helpful when trying to make a pattern more concise

Comment: `(?(name)...`     *named reference condition (PCRE)* ?

Comment: @revo I've updated my question. I played a lot with the conditional you present above. It doesn't seem to work for forward references. This can be seen here: [Works with backreferences](https://regex101.com/r/LVSE05/1), but [doesn't work with forward references](https://regex101.com/r/LVSE05/2). I may be wrong about this, but I haven't been able to get a working example of forward reference conditionals. Maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: `(?(1)...)` means if first capturing group is matched, doesn't mean match next character by recusing first capturing group. I think you are looking for  something like `(?2)(yes|no)(x?)`

Comment: Although you may know such a cluster definition, you are mixing up logics. I never tried to go through whole problem but definitely what I call forward references [exist in PCRE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html).

Comment: [Is this](https://regex101.com/r/LVSE05/3) what you are looking for? otherwise I have no idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: For sure you can't use forward references this way. Conditional needs an initialized existence which happens on *repetition* `(?:(?(1)...)(x)?)+`. That's due to two things one of which is *how* a conditional statement works. The workaround would be using lookahead as conditional statement not a strict check on matching group itself.

Comment: *...a lookahead (which doesn't actually test if the group exists)*  a lookahead actually tests if a group can exist.

Comment: What differences do you see between `^(x)` and `^(?=(x))` except *matching* and *asserting*?

Comment: I thought the same for a while but later some of your statements didn't make sense to me, so no I don't think like you. Anyway...

Comment: @revo would you mind helping me clean up these comments so as to not cause confusion to future readers? Thanks! :)